# Should there be a comma before ‘too’ in: "Me too"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, orthography

I was taught that it is properly written as "Me, too." But a book (The sixty-eight rooms, by Marianne Malonne) I've recently read uses "Me too."

Which one is correct? Are tone and pronunciation affected?

Comment: Which book? Quote and attribution, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it'd help to remember that comma is not merely to separate phrases, it is also used to denote a very short pause when you speak. When you read "Me, too" aloud, you're expected to pause for a bit directly after saying "Me". "Me too", on the other hand, does not require you to pause

Taking into account those, you'd much more likely to encounter "Me too" when it's meant to be said quickly. There's nothing wrong with that phrase.

Perhaps a bit of context of when this was said can help

Answer (score 0):

The following examples are from Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English. 
None of them has a comma before **too**.

> 1. There were people from all over Europe, and America **too**.
> 2. Can I come **too**?
> 3. ‘I’m feeling hungry.’ ‘Me **too**.’
> 4. It’s a more efficient system and it’s cheaper **too**.

Answer (score 0):

*Me too* is correct.  *Me, too* can be used when you especially want to emphasize *me*.

Answer (score 0):

"Me, too" is a simplification of the sentence: "That is my experience, as well"

Because of this, I tend to favour "Me, too" rather than "Me too".